# Is this an undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Is this the below C code an UB? can I access garbage value? if so,can `static function` make it working fine?

```
const char *foo_name(int x){
    switch(x) {
       case FOO: return "foo";
       case BAA: return "baa";
       default: return "unknow";
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused if `printf("%s\n",foo_name(FOO));` is ok according to C std.

Comment: Why would it be undefined? You are not accessing any garbage value.

Comment: the strings exist you are just returning the pointer to it. Its not garbage values... Also you misspelled bar

Comment: @Jack: What is your question about specifically? What exactly makes you suspect your function of UB?

Comment: @AndreyT: Because I was thinking that the string behave as "auto". when the functions end up,all allocated memory to function could be cleaned making its return value garbage value. It worked in my C compiler,but I wanted to make sure that it is std and not an extension or somethings like this. I had bad experiences with gcc sometime ago. Now is clean that string literals have static storage duration. I'm going to accept the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String literals have static storage duration, which means they exist throughout the lifetime of the program. There's no undefined behavior in your code.

Answer (score 3):

No UB here. The standard says that string literals have static storage duration.

> if so, can `static` function make it working fine?

For functions, the `static` modifier means something completely different - it wouldn't solve your (apparently nonexistent) problem.